# How to scroll to location in google map and click on it

Tags: android, selenium, appium

I need to scroll to location in google map and then click on this location. The problem is, that there are no locator for this element. How to do it without locator?

Comment: what do you mean there is no locator? and why do you have to scroll why cant you just type a location into the search bar for google maps?

Comment: There are an area on map, without locator. I can type a location into search bar, but then I need to click on this area. How to do it?

Answer (score -2):

**You can use NestedScrollView to solve your issue**

Comment: Can I use it for appium, selemium?

Comment: No you can use only in android

Comment: I need for appium.

Comment: in no way shape or form does this help him at all